# Is there a simple way to reshape a token object to documents in quanteda?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I am trying to clean some text data, and after tokenising and e.g. removing punctuation, I want my transform the token object into a vector/dataframe/corpus.

My current approach is:

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)

raw <- c("This is text #1.", "And a second document...")
tokens <- raw %>% tokens(remove_punct = T)
docs <- lapply(tokens, toString) %>% gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = "")
```

Is there a more "quanteda" or at least a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Just use regex to remove punctuation from the text? Or is your example to simple? Show us what you want as an output, including all the needed removals.

Comment: That is basically what I am doing, right? The issue is that `toString()` returns all tokens in a single string, however seperated by a comma.

Comment: Ah now i see - I am also stemming and removing punctuation with `tokens()`, this is only a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be how I would do it, and it preserves the docnames as element names in your output vector.  (But you can add `USE.NAMES = FALSE` if you don't want to keep them.)

```
> sapply(tokens, function(x) paste(as.character(x), collapse = " "))
                  text1                   text2 
      "This is text #1" "And a second document"
```

You don't need the `library(dplyr)` here.